# Laravel: validate nested resources

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm working on a project with 3 resources: User, Contexts and Task.

User hasMany Context
Context hasMany User

Task belongs To a single user and context.

I want to write ( and test ) a Validator rule that blocks tasks from being created when the User has NOT a relatioship with the Context.

(Basically, you can't create task in a context if you don't have access to it)

Can you help me?

Thanks